# Does ag-grid has Virtual Scroll?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, infinite-scroll

Does anyone know if ag-grid has virtual-scroll  built in? 
I know it does have infinite scroll, but the app i'm building will have a lot of data..

Answer (score 2):

**ag-grid** has *virtual scroll* in all `rowModels`.

*Virtual scroll* and *infinite scroll* are not the same thing like suggested in the other answer.

*Virtual scroll* keeps only the rows currently viewed by the user in the DOM which tremendously improves the the performance of the application.

In an infinite scrolling table, if *virtual scroll* is not implemented, the browser might even crash not being able to handle large data. All row models including `ClientSide` row model and `Infinite Scroll` row model supports *virtual scroll*.

More information can be found in the official documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/dom-virtualisation/

Comment: it would be nice if there were links to where in their documentation these things exist. Even with your comment, I still have no idea how to implement virtual scrolling in AG Grid.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, here is a [link with the answer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/)

Turn on infinite scroll:

```
 // before grid initialised
 gridOptions.rowModelType = 'infinite';
 gridOptions.datasource = myDataSource;

 // after grid initialised, you can set or change the datasource
 gridOptions.api.setDatasource(myDataSource);
```

Comment: Virtual scroll and infinite scroll are not the same thing. ag-grid has virtual scroll in all rowModels. Virtual scroll keeps only the rows currently viewed by the user in the DOM which tremendously improves the the performance of the application. In a infinite scrolling table, if virtual scroll is not implemented, the browser might even crash not able to handle large data. All row models including ClientSide row model and Infinite Scroll row model supports virtual scroll.

Comment: @abd995, can you please create an answer. Not everyone will read comments and people will stay confused. Thank you for your answer, btw.

Comment: @Anatoly Thank you for pointing it out, wrote an answer based on the comment.